# I want to post my 'raw code' at 'Markdown'

Tags: html, markdown, jekyll, liquid, syntaxhighlighter

I want to post my 'raw code' but it doesn't.
I put my 'html code' but it shows my url.

I use Jekyll theme 'Mediumish'.

Raw Code

```html
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <a href="http://hits.dwyl.com/{{ site.url | remove_first: 'https://' | remove_first: 'http://' }}{{ page.url }}" target="_blank">
    <img src="http://hits.dwyl.com/{{ site.url | remove_first: 'https://' | remove_first: 'http://' }}{{ page.url }}.svg"/>
  </a>
</div>
```

Page show

```html
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <a href="http://hits.dwyl.com/localhost:4000/GithubBlog_8/" target="_blank">
    <img src="http://hits.dwyl.com/localhost:4000/GithubBlog_8/.svg" />
  </a>
</div>
```

How can I post my raw code and why it does?
Here is my page & code.

[Github Page](https://azzyjk.github.io/GithubBlog_8)
[Repository](https://github.com/azzyjk/azzyjk.github.io)

Comment: I guess this is _slightly_ clearer than [last time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62744161/i-want-to-show-my-raw-code-at-syntax-highlighter)... are you asking how to add a code block?

Comment: Thank u for your advice .
But I already know how to add code block.
My question's answer is 'liquid raw tag'...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends what you means by raw, but I guess, here that you don't want your liquid tags to be interpreted.

In this case, you just need to use the [`raw`](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/tags/raw/) tag.

```html
{% raw %}
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <a href="http://hits.dwyl.com/{{ site.url | remove_first: 'https://' | remove_first: 'http://' }}{{ page.url }}" target="_blank">
    <img src="http://hits.dwyl.com/{{ site.url | remove_first: 'https://' | remove_first: 'http://' }}{{ page.url }}.svg"/>
  </a>
</div>
{% endraw %}
```

---

On the other hand if you mean that the HTML should not be processed by your browser, then you need to use the HTML [`pre`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp) tag:

```html
<pre>
  <div style="text-align: center;">
    <a href="http://hits.dwyl.com/{{ site.url | remove_first: 'https://' | remove_first: 'http://' }}{{ page.url }}" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://hits.dwyl.com/{{ site.url | remove_first: 'https://' | remove_first: 'http://' }}{{ page.url }}.svg"/>
    </a>
  </div>
</pre>
```

---

And then, of course, if you need neither to be processed, you can combine both:

```html
{% raw %}
<pre>
  <div style="text-align: center;">
    <a href="http://hits.dwyl.com/{{ site.url | remove_first: 'https://' | remove_first: 'http://' }}{{ page.url }}" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://hits.dwyl.com/{{ site.url | remove_first: 'https://' | remove_first: 'http://' }}{{ page.url }}.svg"/>
    </a>
  </div>
</pre>
{% endraw %}
```

Comment: Yes, I read 'liquid' official document.
But I missed 'raw' tag.
I add 'raw' tag, so it works well.
Thank u for your answer! :)